# Overflow error in poisson distribution implementation

Tags: python, lambda, overflow

I'm trying to implement a poisson distribution as a lambda function in my code:

```
likelihood = lambda lamb: lamb**S / math.factorial(S) * numpy.exp(-lamb)
```

S has the value 124. Now the compiler returns me the following error, in the line in which I define the function:

```
OverflowError: (34, 'Numer ical result out of range')
```

What did I do wrong with implementing that lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably want to be working on a log scale; i.e. log-likelihoods.  this is pretty common in stats as likelihoods are generally pretty small and floating point numbers only really work down to ~1e-300.

I think this function would look something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import loggamma

def log_likelihood(lamb, S):
  return np.log(lamb) * S - loggamma(S + 1) - lamb
```

Comment: @nick-mast has just corrected an error where I wasn't taking the log of `lamb` in the first term.  not sure how I missed this when I wrote it!